# How to read Azure Ad group objectids in identity server?

Tags: server, azure-active-directory, identity

I am using azure ad login in Identity server. I have enabled groups for user profile. But when I login to identity server then group object ids are not coming the claim list. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the `groupMembershipClaims` property to "All" in the AD app's manifest.

For more information, please refer to [Azure Active Directory Part 4: Group Claims](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/).